# + expected input to be a number but got the TRUE/FALSE true instead

Tags: netlogo

Keep getting this error, but variables are not true/false... they are numbers. attached full code for the model below. The section with the error is attached first followed by the entire code (including the error section)

The model shows turtles as cows and patches as grass. The error is stemming from the grow-grass function where each tick, the patches grow by a specified amount. This worked previously, but now is returning an error...

"+ expected input to be a number but got the TRUE/FALSE true instead."

```
to grow-grass
      ask patches [
        set grass-energy grass-energy + regrow-energy
      ]
    end


turtles-own [energy]
patches-own [grass-energy]


to setup
  clear-all
  setup-patches
  setup-turtles
  reset-ticks
end

to scatter
  clear-turtles
  setup-turtles
end


to go
  if ticks >= time-limit [ stop ]
  move-turtles
  check-patches
  eat-grass
  grow-grass
  reproduce
  check-death
  tick
end

to move-turtles
  ask turtles [
  ifelse move-left?
  [ left random 45
    forward 1
    set energy energy - move-energy ]
  [ right random 360
    forward 1
    set energy energy - move-energy ]
  ]
end

to eat-grass
  ask turtles [
    if pcolor = green [
      set energy energy + energy-from-grass
      set grass-energy grass-energy - energy-from-grass
    ]
    ifelse show-energy?
    [ set label energy ]
    [set label "" ]
  ]
end

to reproduce
  ask turtles [
    if energy >= reproduce-energy [
      set energy energy - birth-energy
      hatch 1 [ set energy birth-energy ]]
  ]
end

to check-death
  ask turtles [
    if energy <= 0 [ die ]
  ]
end

to check-patches
  ask patches with [count turtles-here >= 2] 
  [ ask one-of turtles-here [ ask other turtles-here[set energy     energy - (energy / 2)]]]
end

to grow-grass
  ask patches [
    set grass-energy grass-energy + regrow-energy
  ]
end

to setup-patches
  ask n-of green-patches patches [ set pcolor green set grass-energy     grass-energy + grass-alive ]
  ask patches [ 
    if pcolor = black [ set pcolor brown set grass-energy grass-    energy = 0 ]
  ]
end

to setup-turtles
  create-turtles number [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor ]
  ask turtles [ set energy energy + birth-energy set shape "cow" set     size 1.5 ]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is coming from your `setup-patches` procedure, where you say:

```
set grass-energy grass-energy = 0
```

This sets the value of the `grass-energy` variable to the value of the expression `grass-energy = 0`, which reports `true` or `false`.

I think you probably meant to just write `set grass-energy 0`.

The fact that NetLogo uses `set variable value` instead of `variable = value` to change the value of a variable can sometimes be a bit confusing for people coming from other languages, but one generally gets to used to it quickly enough.

Comment: Thats it. Thank you